# What is the physiological criterion for death?

Tags: death

Modern medicine determines death by neurological criteria, but various religious groups may have reservations. For example, orthodox Jews require all vital functions to fail and do not consider a patient breathing on a respirator as dead. What is the Hindu physiological criterion of death?

Comment: I think the criterion is stop of a heart function, but right now I don't have a quotation from some Hindu scripture to back up that.

Answer (score 2):

Physiological criterion of death is provided in **Shreemad Bhagvat Purana (Canto 3 Chapter 31 Verse 44 & 45)**
The answer is given by **"sage Kapila"** , Who is proponent of **"Sankhya Philosophy**". The topic of this chapter in which it's describe is - SB 3.31: Lord Kapila’s Instructions on the Movements of the Living Entities.[**See Here**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/31/)

> जीवो ह्यस्यानुगो देहो भुतेन्द्रिय मनोमय:।
>  तन्निरोधोsस्य
>   **मरण**माविर्भावस्तु सम्भव॥44॥
>
> jīvo hy asyānugo deho bhūtendriya-mano-mayaḥ tan-nirodho ’sya **maraṇam**
>   āvirbhāvas tu sambhavaḥ
>
> Meaning - In this way the living entity gets a suitable body with a
>   material mind and senses, according to his fruitive activities. **When**
>   the **reaction of his particular activity comes to an end, that end is
>   called death,** and when a particular type of reaction begins, that
>   beginning is called birth. [**SB 3.31.44**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/31/44)
>
> ---
>
> **And the exact and Precise criterion of death is given in next verse**
>
> द्रव्योपलब्धिस्थानस्य द्रव्येक्षायोग्यता यदा।
>   तत्पश्चत्वमहंमानादुतत्पत्ति र्द्रव्यदर्शनम॥४५॥
>
> dravyopalabdhi-sthānasya dravyekṣāyogyatā yadā
>  tat pañcatvam
>   ahaṁ-mānād utpattir dravya-darśanam
>
> Meaning - **When the eyes lose their power to see color or form due to
>   morbid affliction of the optic nerve, the sense of sight becomes
>   deadened. The living entity, who is the seer of both the eyes and the
>   sight, loses his power of vision. In the same way, when the physical
>   body, the place where perception of objects occurs, is rendered
>   incapable of perceiving, that is known as death.**[**SB 3.31.45**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/31/45-46)

Here what Sage Kaplia telling us is , "The **subtle body** ,mind and various body parts (Indtiya, इंद्रिय) remains attached  until a jiva attain moksha or liberation.This  **gross body** is a place where jiva(soul) experiences material pleasures.Both this Gross & subtle bodies when gets united its called Birth and **When these gross and subtle bodies stops working in unity then its called death.**

Comment: That doesn't answer the question! The question was about criterion that determines when phenomenon of death occurs, such as stop of a certain bodily functions.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa - Yes , I know that.But i think that topic ( such as stop of a certain bodily functions) is more related science of  Ayurveda.Also you can see that according to modern medicine also body & mind are closely related.So IMO we can't seprate mind from body.In that sense my answer is correct.

Comment: I don't say your answer is not correct, I'm just saying that it doesn't answer the question. The question was about criterion that determines when phenomenon of death occurs, such as stop of a certain bodily functions. In your answer you didn't say anything in this regard. You just said "Gross and Subtle bodies stops working in unity". But that's very broadly said. Asker of the question didn't want such an answer. See his question above.

Comment: Also you quoted from the vedabase.com ... that's not the Gita press version.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa His answer is absolutely correct. Stopping of bodily functions has nothing to do with death. Yogis can stop their organs at will and yet continue to live as if nothing happened.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Asker of the question asked a question about a person dying at the hospital, and he even gave an example of a patient connected to the respiratory device. So obviously he didn't ask about a yogi, but he asked about an ordinary person who is dying. For such a person stopping of the bodily functions certainly has something to do with his death.

Comment: @brahmajijnasa First of all, there is no difference between death of ordinary person and yogi. Death means death, simple as that. OP knows modern criterion for death but he asked this question on this site because he wants to know what actually happens for which the person can be declared dead.

Comment: I feel the transation of the verse of 3.31.45 is http://www.bhagavata.org/canto3/chapter31.html rather than the one shared in the link. Even the word by word translation present in the link differs from the sentence form of the translation.